# Laravel 5.1 installation - white screen and no .env file

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have a problem setting up Laravel 5.1 on my iMac with OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

It's the first time I try to set it up on a Mac. Normally I use Windows and never had a problem. I have no problems with oder websites I have created, with or without vhosts.

I use the built-in apache2 server with php enabled and mysql installed. I modified my httpd.conf in order to be able to use the /Users/Fabian/Sites folder for my sites. I also created a virtual-host pointing to /Users/Fabian/Sites/Laravel/public.

At first, I installed composer globally. Next step was to install Laravel by:

```
cd /Users/Fabian/Sites
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel
```

So the download started and finished without any errors.

But now, my .env file is missing. I went to Github and copied the example-.env file from laravel/laravel repository. Now it looks like this:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=junperbo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

I have no app_key.

When I try to enter the Site via http://laravel.me I only get a white screen. There is nothing. No errors. Not even a source-code. laravel.me is my vhost pointing to /Users/Fabian/Sites/Laravel/public. And yes, it is set up in my /etc/hosts file ;)

Any ideas what went wrong during installation? Is there something I have to do in a different way on a Mac? I did the installation without sudo.

Everytime I try to enter the site my custom_log says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2015:09:42:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2015:09:42:53 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here is my httpd.conf file: [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/twbTNnKK)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also faced similar problem. After doing some research , I found that laravel didn't support the php version.

```
laravel 5.1 will support only PHP >= 5.5.9
laravel 5.0 will support only PHP >= 5.4
laravel 4.2 will support only PHP >= 5.4
```

So,before set upping your laravel  project make sure that the server requirements for the laravel are satisfied.

For more information see  [Laravel Site](http://laravel.com/docs/master)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your suggest. It seems that this solved my problem. But instead of the built in apache server I have installed the newest version of XAMPP with php version 5.6.12.  After a litte configuration everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the `.env` file is actually called that and not `.env.example` as your app will look for and use `.env`.

As for the `APP_KEY`, you can generate this by using this command `php artisan key:generate`.

Does this solve your problem at all? Let me know if it doesn't and we'll go from there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this doesn't work.. Perhaps something with mod_rewrite?

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite? Also, check your logs to see what kind of error is being thrown.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled. Now, after a fresh installation of Laravel, there is a .env file and the APP_KEY was set correctly. Currently I have no errors in my logs, not in the logs defined in my vhost for the current project and no errors in the apache logs. My browser says, that the website is not available with "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Can you access it by using the IP address instead of localhost?